# Using quartz job scheduler for changing time trigger

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling

I need a solution for this problem. Please help me if anybody knows how I can use Quartz scheduler for this purpose, or if any other JobScheduler exists let me know.

I have a list of Date like this

> 2015-11-18 01:14:03
>
> 2015-11-18 01:50:03
>
> 2015-11-18 02:24:03
>
> 2015-11-18 03:04:03
>
> 2015-11-18 04:16:03
>
> 2015-11-18 05:54:03
>
> 2015-11-18 06:24:03
>
> 2015-11-18 07:17:03
>
> 2015-11-18 08:34:03

I need the Scheduler to trigger the function as per the list time (assume that the times are in sorted order). How can I do this on quartz jobs?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to format the time as a CRON expression.

More details are at:
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger